# How to compile and build a very simple Gnu linux application to Windows using Mingw or Cygwin?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, ubuntu, mingw32

I would like to port an existing Linux application from its plain C/C++ source
code to Windows XP/Vista/7 exactly same functionality to have, without losing
few modules here and there etc. Basic codes are fine to build, but problem is
the application I will be porting have other Linux dependencies.

Question: How can I port a C/C++ code which has other libraries dependencies, to
Windows system? Using MinGW. Is there any IDE where I can do that? Or first of
all I need to find out dependent libraries. And then finally build the main
application?

Would it be possible to advise, a hello world for such application or reference
to any resource which really works. Because I tried myself and i get fail
building the other dependencies it has using MinGW. Follow up:

1. installing Cygwin

   1. http://cygwin.com/setup.exe
   2. C:/cygwin
   3. make sure checked all gcc/g++/svn/wget etc...
2. install apt-cyg (good if it was default)

   ```
   wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg
   install apt-cyg /bin
   ```
3. figured out that, this are related libraries for your apps

   ```
   apt-cyg install libxml2 iconv bison flex pkg-config
   ```
4. install Linux apps to Windows apps

   ```
   wget site/download/staffs
   tar xvfz staffs.tar.gz # your time saver apps
   ./configure
   make
   make install
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MinGW is, by nature, minimalist; it tries hard not to bring any baggage with it. It sounds like you actually *want* baggage, in which case rather than using MinGW you should be using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com), which emulates/implements many UNIX system calls and libraries on Windows. The whole GNU toolchain is there, and many times you can just run `./configure` and `make` and everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks, i started your advise, and will update above my follow up. Hope i get success.

Comment: It works! but the build that i prepare, how can i copy this setup to keep it for future? Without re-inventing this whole procedure?

Comment: When we build apps using CygWin does it create any DLL files? or Any references to later reuse. Or it is done by MinGW? I have updates above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Running on an emulation layer (a good suggestion) will get you going quickly, but it will be sub-optimal.

Depending on your performance requirements, you may have to retool the app to replace the Linux-dependent code with either portable alternatives such as Boost or other portable library code, or Windows-specific replacement code of your own.

Comment: Yes for performence tips you are very correct, i can see while building and installing its very slow, they main goal for this is to learn how it works. And after seeing a face of success, i will optimize it. I prefer seeing first and doing it. thanks, i just update with working update!